# Iterate through grouped collection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, collections

I want to iterate through collections, but I'm having difficulty in achieving this,since I'm new to this. Below I am showing my data.

```
 user: Array [1]
       0. Object
           id:8
           products:Object
              3: Array[2]
                 0: Object
                     value: 25
                     id:4
                1: Object
                     value: 20
                     id:5
               4: Array[3]
                   0: Object
                       value: 14
                       id:6
                   1: Object
                      value: 30
                      id:7
                   1: Object
                      value: 20
                      id:8
```

So I want to get value, in order to sum them for each grouped collection. Sum of collection 3 =a, sum of collection 4=b, etc.

I tried as below but I get nothing:

```
data:{
                user:[],
         }
methods:{
                watchedOnly(){
                    var self = this;
                    for(var product in self.user.products ){
                            for (var key in product){
                                if(product.hasOwnProperty('key')){
                                    console.log(product[key]);
                                 }
                            }

                    }
                }, }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I'm not sure what you want to sum up. Also, `this.data` is an array, not an object which means that the `this.user.products` is `undefined`.

Comment: @str I want to sum values, for each grouped array. for array with id 3 the sum would be different from 4, etc. But I cannot get the values in the loop.

Comment: Provide, copy / paste example of real structure of your data. Structure you wrote manually is chaotic and improperly structured.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky i just edited, cannot provide all the data that would be too much :)

Comment: @jenny Look at my answer and leave comment

Comment: @VladislavLadicky yes, that's right

Comment: @jenny Ok, example function consoling sums added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, leave comment if your real data have structure like this, then I edit this answer:

```
let user = [
  {
    id: 8,
    products: {
      3: [
        {id: 4, value: 25},
        {id: 5, value: 20}
      ],
      4: [
        {id: 6, value: 14},
        {id: 7, value: 30},
        {id: 8, value: 20}
      ]
    }
  }
]

function sum (arr) {
  Object
    .entries(arr[0].products)
    .forEach(pair => {
      let sum = Array
        .from(pair[1].map(o => o.value))
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
      console.log(`Sum for product ${pair[0]} is ${sum}`)
    })
}

sum(user)
```

Or in Vue component:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      user: []
    }
  },

  computed: {
    watchedOnly () {
      let result = {}

      Object
        .entries(this.user[0].products)
        .forEach(pair => {
          let sum = Array
            .from(pair[1].map(o => o.value))
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
          result[pair[0]] = sum
        })

      return result
    }
  }
}
```

Use it in template:

```
<p v-for="(sum, product) in watchedOnly">
  Sum for product {{ product }} is {{ sum }}
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks  so much, I wasn't expecting for all of it :)